# What are the constant solutions for separation of variables used for?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my calc $2$ textbook there is an initial-value problem that requires the use of separation of variables.

> The differential equation is $\frac{dy}{dx} = \left(2x+3\right)\left(y^2-4\right)$ with initial value $y(0)=1$.

In the list of steps to take to solve this equation using separation of variables, the very first step is "Check for any values of $y$ that make $g(y) = 0$. These correspond to constant solutions". When I solve $g(y)=0$ I get $g(y) = \pm 2$, but I don't really understand how these values are used to solve this equation?

Answer (score 2):

You need to solve an **initial value problem** so you need:

1. Solve the ordinary differential equation.
2. Use the **initial condition** for to find the constants.

For example, in your problem you have the following initial value problem (an ordinary differential equation+ initial condition).

\begin{eqnarray*}
(\mathbf{IVP}): \left\{\begin{aligned} \frac{dy}{dx}=(2x+3)(y^{2}-4), \\ y(0)=1 .\end{aligned} \right.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, *first* we solve the ordinary differential equation (ODE) $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=(2x+3)(y^{2}-4)$ indeed, this's a separate ODE so we have $$ \frac{dy}{dx}=(2x+3)(y^{2}-4) \implies \frac{1}{y^{2}-4}dy=(2x+3)dx \implies \int \frac{1}{y^{2}-4}dy=\int (2x+3)dx$$
note that  that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{1}{y^{2}-4}dy&=&\int \frac{1}{(y-2)}\frac{1}{(y+2)}dy\\
&=&\int \frac{A}{y-2}dy+\int \frac{B}{y+2}dy\\
&=&\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{1}{y-2}dy-\frac{1}{4}\int \frac{1}{y+2}dy
\end{eqnarray*}
since that  $$1=A(y+2)+B(y-2) \implies \left\{\begin{aligned} y=-2 \implies 1=-4B \implies B=-\frac{1}{4}\\ y=2 \implies 1=4A \implies A=\frac{1}{4}\end{aligned} \right.$$
so, we have $$\int \frac{1}{y^{2}-4}dy=\frac{1}{4}\ln|y-2|-\frac{1}{4}\ln|y+2|+c$$
Therefore
$$\int \frac{1}{y^{2}-4}dy=\int (2x+3)dx \implies \boxed{\frac{1}{4}\ln|y-2|-\frac{1}{4}\ln|y+2|=x^{2}+3x+\ln|C|}$$
2. Using the initial condition, since $y(0)=1$, we have $$ \frac{1}{4}\cdot 0-\frac{1}{4}\cdot 0 =\ln|C| \iff \ln|C|=0 \implies |C|=e^{0}=1 \implies \boxed{C=\pm 1}$$
3. So, the solution for the initial value problem is $$\boxed{\frac{1}{4}\ln|y-2|-\frac{1}{4}\ln|y+2|=x^{2}+3x \pm 1}$$

Answer (score 0):

In this case, when $y(0)=1$, those constant solutions don't play a role.

But if the initial condition were $y(0)=2$, then the solution would be $y(t)=2$ (for all $t$), and likewise with $y(0)=-2$ you would get $y(t)=-2$. And those two solutions can't be obtained by writing $dy/(y^2-4)=(2x+3)dx$, since when you're dividing by $y^2-4$ you have to assume that $y \neq \pm 2$.

Answer (score 0):

In the separation of variables, the first step is division by $(y^2-4)$. As with any division, you want to prevent division by zero. So $y\ne \pm 2$. From the other direction, $y(t)=\pm2$ are constant solutions. The equation is locally Lipschitz, so all solutions are unique, do not cross or touch each other. So for any solution with an initial value not on these constant solutions, all other values will also stay away from these constants. Thus for the solution under consideration, the division is unproblematic.